# Where do I ask about recording game objects?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am looking for a site where I can ask about recording the type, position and velocity of game objects in a scene, with the values recorded relative to the camera in such a way, that I can use the information along with extracting the game's internal models and textures, as well as any other visual modifier info, in order to draw a new frame from scratch by directly interpolating the object positions based on the known object positions and the object velocities.

This is for an already existing game that I have not made.

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you're asking if you correct grammar (e.g. I vs i) and break up your sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what your question is exactly, but you might be able to get an answer on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).
Be sure to check out their Help page on what's on-topic [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)—and to add a lot more details to your question.

I think the possibility of getting an answer completely depends on the engine and/or programming language used by the game.